# Prove a Bernoulli polynomial equation: $B_s(x+y)=\sum_{j=0}^s \binom{s}{j} B_{j}(x)\cdot y^{s-j}$

Tags: bernoulli-numbers, bernoulli-polynomials

I want to show the equation for Bernoulli polynomials $B_s(x+y)$:
$$B_s(x+y)=\sum_{j=0}^s \binom{s}{j} B_{j}(x)\cdot y^{s-j}$$
I begin with:
$$B_s(z)=\sum_{j=0}^s \binom{s}{j} B_{s-j} \cdot z^j$$
Replace $z$ with $x+y$
$$B_s(x+y)=\sum_{j=0}^s \binom{s}{j} B_{s-j} \cdot(x+y)^j$$
where $B_{s-j}$ is Bernoulli coefficient.

Next, I do the binomial expansion for $(x+y)^j=\sum_{k=0}^j \binom{j}{k} x^k \cdot y^{j-k}$

So we got:
$$B_s(x+y)=\sum_{j=0}^s \binom{s}{j} B_{s-j} \cdot \sum_{k=0}^j \binom{j}{k} x^k \cdot y^{j-k}$$

I guess next step is to do the variable transformation from $j,k$ to some other index, how should I define the variable transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EGF of Bernoulli polynomials is

$$\frac{t\exp(xt)}{\exp(t)-1} =
\sum_{n\ge 0} B_n(x) \frac{t^n}{n!}.$$

We seek to show that

$$B_s(x+y) = \sum_{j=0}^s {s\choose j} B_j(x) y^{s-j}
= \sum_{j=0}^s {s\choose j} B_{s-j}(x) y^j.$$

The RHS is

$$\sum_{j=0}^s {s\choose j} y^j
(s-j)! [t^{s-j}]
\frac{t\exp(xt)}{\exp(t)-1}
\\ = s! [t^s]
\frac{t\exp(xt)}{\exp(t)-1}
\sum_{j\ge 0} \frac{1}{j!} y^j t^j.$$

Now here we have extended $j$ to infinity because the coefficient
extractor in $t$ enforces the upper limit through $t^j.$ Continuing,

$$s! [t^s]
\frac{t\exp(xt)}{\exp(t)-1} \exp(yt)
= s! [t^s] \frac{t\exp((x+y)t)}{\exp(t)-1}
= B_s(x+y).$$

This is the claim.

**Remark.** We can also start from

$$B_s(x+y) = \sum_{j=0}^s {s\choose j} B_{s-j}
\sum_{k=0}^j {j\choose k} x^{j-k} y^k
\\ = \sum_{k=0}^s x^{-k} y^k
\sum_{j=k}^s B_{s-j} {s\choose j} {j\choose k} x^j.$$

We have

$${s\choose j} {j\choose k}
= \frac{s!}{(s-j)! \times k! \times (j-k)!}
= {s\choose k} {s-k\choose j-k}$$

and obtain

$$\sum_{k=0}^s {s\choose k} x^{-k} y^k
\sum_{j=k}^s B_{s-j} {s-k\choose j-k} x^j
\\ = \sum_{k=0}^s {s\choose k} y^k
\sum_{j=0}^{s-k} B_{s-k-j} {s-k\choose j} x^j
\\ = \sum_{k=0}^s {s\choose k} y^k B_{s-k}(x)
= \sum_{k=0}^s {s\choose k} B_{k}(x) y^{s-k}.$$

Again we have the claim.

Comment: Sorry, how  is the notation $[t^s]$ defined?

Comment: This is the [coefficient extractor for formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Extracting_coefficients).

Comment: (1) why $[t^{s-j}] f(x,t)=[t^s]f(x,t) t^j$?, (2) why you can extend the upper limit from $s$ to $\infty$

Comment: (1) Note that $[t^{s-j}] \sum_{n\ge  0} q_n t^n = q_{s-j}.$ But we also have that $[t^s] \sum_{n\ge 0} q_n t^{n+j}$ is the coefficient with $n+j=s$ or $n=s-j$ so we again get $q_{s-j}.$ This also follows by inspection. (2) Well if $j\gt s$ we get that $t^j$ does not contribute to $[t^s]$, so we may include those $j$ with no change.

Comment: (2). Here we also use that the Bernoulli polynomial EGF is a formal power series that starts with a constant term. Multiply by $t^j$ and the series starts at $j$, hence no contribution when $j\gt s.$

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understand this method. This is the first time to see this trick! But I am wondering if there is a straightforward way to derive this equation? For example from this step: $B_s(x+y)=\sum_{j=0}^s \binom{s}{j} B_{s-j} \cdot \sum_{k=0}^j \binom{j}{k} x^k \cdot y^{j-k}$

Comment: Now that there is some activity on the question you might see another answer.

Answer (score 1):

This method uses the [Umbral calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbral_calculus).
Define the linear map
$$ L_B( B^n ) := B_n $$
where $B_n$ is the Bernoulli numbers. The key result is
$$ B_n(z) = L_B( (B+z)^n ) = L_B\left(\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} B^k z^{n-k} \right) = \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} B_k z^{n-k}.$$
Apply this result to your case with
$$ B_n(x+y) = L_B( (B+x+y)^n ) = L_B(((B+x)+y)^n) =\\
L_B\left(\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (B+x)^k y^{n-k} \right) = \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} B_k(x) y^{n-k}. $$